# Driving LED light chain that needs voltage switching

Tags: transistors, nodemcu

I have some LED party lights with a defect controller. If you power it "+/-", only the odd ones are illuminating, on "-/+" only the even ones.

Now I want to drive them using a ESP12 (NodeMCU). Programming of the controller is no problem, but it doesn't provide enough current.

I got one of these "Electronics-Starter-Kits" which also comes with some 2N2222 NPN Transistors, Diodes and stuff and I was experimenting whole day long but I am stuck.

I have two PWM outputs on the ESP12 and connected one (D1) to a transistor which lets me control the odd ones (Emitter to GND, one end of the led chain to the collector and one to +5V). To have the other ones illuminating, I would need to set D1 to LOW and D2 to HIGH and switch it real fast. But how do I switch GND on the other end of the led chain respectively?

Does someone have an idea and could point me in the right direction?

Edit:
This is my last (working) setup:
No Idea on how to move on, tbh ..
[image: Fritzing]

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to show us a schematic of what you've built.

Comment: Google "led H-Bridge". Though you'll need some matching pnp transistors.

Comment: @brhans added my last setup!

Comment: @Passerby okay, I will take a look, ty!

Comment: Would a L293D be a possible solution for my problem?

Comment: you can't do anything until you specify the LED V, and amps